# Spring with no view resolver but plain html

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to configure Spring to use only my html files instead of jsp view resolver but can't get it to work. I tried many different configurations and I simply want to have redirection to /WEB-INF/views/index.html everytime localhost:8080/ is entered. Now what I have in my tomcat console is:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for
>   HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/index.html] in DispatcherServlet
>   with name 'appServlet'.

here's my `servlet-context.xml` snippet.

```
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value="" />
</beans:bean>
<view-controller path="/" view-name="index.html"/>
```

Any suggestions what am I missing?

EDIT-
web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>

    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question so this is for anyone who comes here now. Spring is auto-configured to pick up your views as long as your file paths are correct, so you should not have to do any `spring webmvc configuration`.

I ran into this issue in Intellij and simply had to restart the application and the error was gone.  Hope someone sees this and doesn't spend hours working on this.

Answer (score 0):

This error

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'.
```

is telling us that you are actually going to the following address

```
localhost:8080/WEB-INF/views/index.html
```

which obviously makes no sense.

If you want

> to have redirection to /WEB-INF/views/index.html everytime
>   localhost:8080/ is entered

add a welcome file to your deployment descriptor.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>WEB-INF/views/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: now I have `WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'` :(

Comment: @xwhyz What url is your `DispatcherServlet` mapped to? While you're at it just post your full config.

Comment: @xwhyz Does the file `WEB-INF/views/index.html` really exist where you say it does?

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/6fvdizbsn/paaaath.png whis is how it looks now, I have two index.html 'just in case'

Comment: @xwhyz Just to try and find the issue, remove your `<servlet>` declaration and see what happens. Recompile and rebuild your project. It wouldn't hurt to check your servlet-context configuration for things that might interfere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a / to the prefix.

```
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value="" />
</beans:bean>
<view-controller path="/" view-name="index.html"/>
```